# Packaging ANE, the file you chose is not inside a project

Tags: flash, actionscript, ane

This is my first time building an ANE and I have run into some problems. I have made some changes to this ANE: https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Facebook

I had to make some minor changes to the build config files, but it builds fine. The problem I am getting is when I am debugging and try using the ANE. I get an error saying there is a null reference. The funny thing is, the source code it refers to as the problem is the source folder from where I built the ANE, as if the ANE file is linking to this folder instead of them being packaged in the file.. I also get a popup saying "the file you chose is not inside a project". I am using Flash Builder 4.6 and I checked that the "package" checkbox in project settings has been checked.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Jacob

Comment: Have you tried packaging using the original ane instead of the one you made minor changes to? You may find an error has crept in somewhere...

Comment: I have not. I will try this and post an update, thanks!